# Footer content (document name) to auto update in Powerpoint

Tags: powerpoint, powerpoint-2013

I'm trying to add the document name to my footer in powerpoint, and for it to auto populate when the document is saved. is this possible?

I know it's used in microsoft word with autotext but i can't see a similar feature in ppt

Answer (score 0):

PowerPoint doesn't have a similar feature.  This could be accomplished with an add-in but otherwise, no.

Comment: You'd do it with macros (ie, VBA) but they'd have to live in an add-in; in order to trap e.g. Save events, you pretty much have to have your code in an add-in.  You could, however, write VBA that'd do the job when a user runs it or clicks an "Update footer" button.  Still, it'd be better to do this in an add-in so the user doesn't have to open the file that contains the code, press Alt+F8, find the right macro and launch it (aka: They won't bother)